# EF Core 7 - SQL Server - JsonColumn boolean value is stored as string and failing to parse later

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've got an entity A with a field of type B. B has several nullable props, and others stuff not relevant to the question.

Packages intalled:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.8"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.8" />
```

Context config:

```cs
builder.Entity<A>(a =>
          {
              a.OwnsOne(a => a.B, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
              {
                  ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
                  ownedNavigationBuilder
                      .Property(x => x.Y)
                      .HasConversion(new EnumToNumberConverter<SomeEnum, int>());
              });
          });
```

Class Definition:

```
class B
{
  public bool? B1 { get; set; } = false;
  public bool? B2 { get; set; } = false;
  public E1? SomeEnum { get; set; } = SomeEnum.SomeValue;
}
```

As you can see, I have converted the enum to int (because of compatibility issues), and it worked well.

I now have another problem, which is that whenever I save an entity A with B, it will store the boolean values as string (like "true" , "false"), and then failing to read them, throwing the following error:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 7.

When I go and check the DB I see the following in the B column (a json within A stored as nvarchar):

```
{
    B1: true,
    B2: "true"
}
```

After this EF Core is unable to parse the data and will not return anything containing "broken" values.

If I replace `"true"` with `true`, then everything works as expected.

This is the call stack:

```
An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Management.Infra.ManagementContext'.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 7.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'String' as a boolean.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_ExpectedBoolean(JsonTokenType tokenType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.BooleanConverter.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.NullableConverter`1.Read(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadUsingMetadata[TValue](JsonElement element, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at lambda_method514(Closure , QueryContext , Object[] , JsonElement )
   at lambda_method513(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , SplitQueryResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

**UPDATE**:

I changed the definition of B. Such that all the fields are not nullable anymore (just removed the `?` from the boolean props). Of course, now it all breaks since not all stored json contain all the fields. After a small migration script I noticed that it works as expected. So this might be a bug when serializing/deserialzing nullable boolean within a JsonColumn.

Not sure if this would work for me since introducing new fields to `B` would require a `JSON_MODIFY` sql query migration script.

Will continue to dig in, and might create an issue on their github if I can repro this on a small gist.

Comment: well, since boolean should be stored in json without quotes `"` - looks like the problem is with the serializing, and not with the parsing

Comment: I think the same. I'm trying with a custom `ValueConverter` but it's blind guessing at this point.

Comment: Why are `B1` and `B2` being serialized differently, what is different about them? Please show the definition of `class B`

Comment: @Charlieface Both are `bool?` 
B1 is the current value, B2 is after I update it.
I will update the question clarifying those things.
I also just found that it works with `bool` but does this strange behaviour only when using `bool?` (Nulalble<bool>).

Comment: I tried it with your configuration and everything worked for me, also with nullable properties. I used the same package version with SQL Server.

Comment: it can be seen from the error text that ef uses System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer, so the problem is somewhere on your side

Answer (score 2):

Definitely EF Core 7 bug. I did not check EF Core 8 preview since I have strong policy of not installing preview software, but you/someone could test if it is fixed there. As far as I can tell, in 8 they are using a new JSON processing primitives, also null value support in value converters, so most likely it will be. The most important is that it is not fixed in the latest 7 (7.0.10 at this time), and due to 7 being STS release, I don't think it will be fixed there.

The issue reproduces **only** during **update** of a **single** `bool?` property of a JSON mapped owned entity type. Adding new owner entity or updating more than one property is ok - EF generates single `varchar` parameter containing the full JSON serialized client side with correct values. However with aforementioned single property partial JSON update, EF is generating `JSON_MODIFY` expression, with `JSON_VALUE` argument **missing** `CAST` operator, which for all other value types and their nullable counterparts is there and ensures correct JSON type. But not for `bool?`. And without that cast, the value is stored as text, and then cannot be read back as bool during the deserialization.

Until the issue is fixed, following is the only workaround I found. Anytime we have such bugs, we start playing with value converters (yes, you can apply value converter for the same type, e.g. `bool` <-> `bool`), and in this particular case the one called `BoolToTwoValuesConverter<TProvider>` did the job. It's a quite weird, but works. All you need is to apply it to any `bool?` property of your JSON mapped objects. For instance,

```cs
var jsonBoolConverter = new BoolToTwoValuesConverter<bool>(false, true);

// ...

ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();

ownedNavigationBuilder.Property(e => e.B1)
    .HasConversion(jsonBoolConverter);

ownedNavigationBuilder.Property(e => e.B2)
    .HasConversion(jsonBoolConverter);
```

Basically emulating `bool` enum with two `bool` values `{ false, true }` :)

Comment: Deep in the EF caves again ;) - "due to 7 being LTS" should be STS right?

Comment: @Gert STS of course, thank you. And good to see you back :)

Comment: Thanks for that approach. But it did not fully work @IvanStoev. 
When adding a new `bool?` to the class and then trying to add a value it throws this error: ` Property cannot be found on the specified JSON path.`

Comment: @JuanCarlos Actually it does work. What are you describing now is a different issue unrelated to `bool?` type property in question. The same happens if you add **any** nullable type property to the class (e.g. `public int? I2 { get; set; }` or `public string? S2 { get; set; }` etc.) and try updating it with value. If you add non nullable property, then you cannot even read the object from db. Anyway, these are separate general issues unrelated to the OP, and must be reported to EFC GitHub issue tracker and ask for resolution/workaround there.

Comment: I think I will write my own abstraction and get over this. Will just use a string and migrate later when this product is actually working and not a half baked one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JuanCarlos You always have/had that option - after all, that was the only option before they added `ToJson` config. The sad thing is that because of this partial update / json data upgrade problem you'll loose the main benefit of the JSON mapping, which is using these JSON object properties inside db queries, e.g. `Select`, `Where` etc. Btw, I found where the `bool?` bug is, it is specific code for SqlServer. The same code in EFC 8 sources is different, but relies on changes in a general purpose class, so cannot be applied directly to 7. If you are allowed/can afford, try EFC 8 before taking

Comment: own way, from what I see there is a big chance all these issues to be fixed there. Here is the source file along with change history if you are interested in https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/commits/main/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Update/Internal/SqlServerUpdateSqlGenerator.cs. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, We have already a migration to EF8 on a staging environment, let's see how it goes. Thanks for the link to the repo, will take a look at it.